# I Can't create a window in pyglet

Tags: python-3.x, pyglet

I have just installed pyglet on my machine. But I can't seem to create a window

here's what I tried

```
import pyglet 

window = pyglet.window.Window()

pyglet.app.run()
```

and it  gives me this error when I run

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Public/Documents/vscode/python/Games/Pyglet/main.py", line 3, in <module>
    window = pyglet.window.Window()
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pyglet\window\win32\__init__.py", line 132, in __init__
    super(Win32Window, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pyglet\window\__init__.py", line 648, in __init__
    self._create()
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pyglet\window\win32\__init__.py", line 274, in _create
    self.context.attach(self.canvas)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pyglet\gl\win32.py", line 238, in attach
    raise gl.ContextException('Unable to share contexts.')
pyglet.gl.ContextException: Unable to share contexts.
```

Comment: same problem with me , are there any one  solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help somebody, i've searching in some forums for the last 2 days and it seems that there's a problem with the Intel HD 4000, and it kinda breaks the pyglet.
Here's the solution that i've found, just change the method create_context in "\gl\win32.py" for this one:

```
def create_context(self, share):
if wgl_info.have_extension('WGL_ARB_create_context') and gl_info.get_vendor() != 'Intel':
return Win32ARBContext(self, share)
else:
return Win32Context(self, share)
```

Hope it works!!